# Should a stand-alone PHP class throw exceptions?

Tags: php, architecture

I'm currently building a stand-alone PHP class to wrap the Instagram API with a few custom code for the types of projects I work on at my company. As I develop my code, I often find myself writing sutff like this:

```
if (!$this->accessToken)
    throw new Exception("Instagram: Access Token can't be NULL", 1);
```

Is this a bad practice? If so, what's the recommended approach to situations like these?

Comment: Why you think stand-alone php class should not throw exceptions? I think your example is fine

Comment: @Kossel My question was to ask for a better way to handle those situations, if there's any. If throwing exceptions is fine, I'm okay with that too.

Comment: I know, and that is a good practice. actually @ajshort has posted all I wanted to say lol. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is good practice, as it allows people using your library to handle errors properly. It's always a good idea to throw an exception when an exceptional circumstance occurs (such as important values being null).

The only improvement I could suggest to use a more specific exception class. For this case, you might want to throw an `InvalidArgumentException` or `UnexpectedValueException`. Using a more specific exception class means that people can check more specifically for that class in `catch` blocks. For more complex applications defining your own exception classes to handle specific exceptions types is a good idea.

Also, it's very helpful for people using IDEs if you annotate the methods which throw exceptions with `@throws` tags.